# Alamofire upload stops when screen is locked

Tags: ios, swift, upload, alamofire, background-process

I have an iOS app that uploads audio files to the server using Alamofire multi-part request. Upload works fine in foreground and background but when screen is locked, upload is stopped and failed. How can I keep uploading files successfully even when screen is locked ?

Comment: you need to use a background task to upload an audio file

Comment: https://medium.com/livefront/uploading-data-in-the-background-in-ios-f93722013c6a

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a background task to upload an audio file [link](https://medium.com/livefront/uploading-data-in-the-background-in-ios-f93722013c6a)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, URLSessionTaskDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let url = URL(string: "http://0.0.0.0")!
        let data = "Secret Message".data(using: .utf8)!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "uniqueId")
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
        let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, from: data)
        task.resume()
    }
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        print("We're done here")
    }
```